# How to get the exit code of a system process?

Tags: haskell, systems-programming

Say I want to execute the command `unrar x archivename` from within Haskell.

What is the best way to do it and how do I get the exit code of the command? If the command exited successfully I want to delete the archive else not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [`process`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.0.1.5) library you will find the function [`readProcessWithExitCode`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/1.0.1.5/doc/html/System-Process.html#v%3areadProcessWithExitCode), which does what you want.  Something like:

```
(e,_,_) <- readProcessWithExitCode "unrar" ["unrar", "x", "-p-", "archivename"] ""
if e == ExitSuccess then ... else ...
```

There are also many other solutions, such as the `system` command.  Take your pick.

Answer (score 3):

The [`readProcessWithExitCode`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/process/System-Process.html#v%3areadProcessWithExitCode) function from `System.Process` should do the job.

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Directory
import System.Exit
import System.Process

main = do
    (exitCode, _, _) <- readProcessWithExitCode "unrar" ["x", "archivename"] ""
    when (exitCode == ExitSuccess) $ removeFile "archivename"
```